# Save in the database values of dropdown

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making a dropdown, and I want when the user select one values, save to the database.

**This is my code**:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM store_locator_bundes");
echo '<select name="bundesland-dropdown">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

And the conditional

```
if($_POST[$criteria['submit']['name']]) {
    // here I am lost, I have to insert the values of the dropdown to store_locator and the field bundes_id
}
```

Thanks for you help ;)

Comment: `$variable = $_POST['bundesland-dropdown']` then INSERT as normal

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO store_locator_bundes (bundes_id) VALUES ('".$variable."')"; like this Milhai

Comment: What do you want to insert into the database? Just the name? Does each store have an id?

Comment: <option>München</option>
<option>München2</option> like this values but only 1 value i want to insert in the field bundes_id but i have to rename bundes_id to bundes_name

Comment: `INSERT INTO store_locator_bundes (bundes_name) VALUES ('$variable') WHERE bundes_name = $variable`

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
$_POST['bundesland-dropdown']; // You want the <select> not the <options>'s name
```

Then for the insert:

```
if (isset($_POST['bundesland-dropdown'])){
    //mysqli/PDO/whatever database method of insertion you want here
}
```